# Filtering using one value that is common in two columns in tableau

Tags: filter, tableau-api

I have a data that contains multiple columns.
I want to create a filter that contains the same value from two columns.
How can I do that?
I have three columns as follow:

```
Home Team     Away Team     Match
    A             B        A Vs B
    C             D        C vs D
    E             F        E Vs F
    G             H        G vs H
    B             D        B vs D
    C             A        C vs A
    H             F        H vs F
    G             E        G vs E
```

You will see teams are common for Home Team and away Team at different rows.
The filter that I want to create will extract the common teams from Home Team and Away Team to extract the Match. The output I want to show after apply filter for let's say A is as follow:

```
Home Team     Away Team     Match
    A             B        A Vs B
    C             A        C vs A
```

In this case, I extracted the match that contains Team A at both Home Team and Away Team.
Thanks
Zep

Comment: didn't exactly understand you question, if you filter you want to show filtered value or combine multiple columns and then filter

Comment: Hi Siva, I have update the question.
Would you mind to have a look?

Comment: sure.. its a better explanation, will post answer todau

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this kind of requirements you need to create a parameter, used your dummy data in question and create a simple report, follow below steps:

Create parameter with any of the field either `Home Team` or `Away Team` now write a condition that will act on both the fields.

Create a calculated field and write below code:

```
[Home Team] = [Away Team Parameter]
OR 
[Away Team] = [Away Team Parameter]  //Here I created parameter with Away Team
```

Now place the calculated field in filter and select `True` and place all fields on sheet.

Check below screenshot

[image]

Comment: Hi @Siva. Thanks for the advice. In addition to above process, I want to work out number of matches that the team in parameter win, draw or lose. How can I do that?

Comment: @Zephyr Can you post a new question with data on win, draw and lose and how data comes to tableau

Comment: Hi Siva thanks. I will post and tag you in the question.